# GKE Menu interface workloads continous delivery

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Since few days I notices in GCP Kubernetes Engine, Workloads actions menu a new command : Continous Delivery. But it's inactive and even the Learn more doesn't work.
Is it a new features, an easy CD integration ? How to use it ?
Thank you

[Menu UI Continous Delivery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztyTt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a feature that will become available in the future,

There’s an issue tracker for this [1], if you follow the link and if logged in with any Google Account, you can click the star on the top left to receive updates on this.

For the meantime, I think that this document it’s what I think the “learn more” will point to [2]. I cannot confirm that this will be the document linked in the future.

Cheers!

---

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/142372527
[2] https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery/